# Focus next input once reaching maxlength in different containers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to focus next input once the input field reach the maxlength, but the input fields are in different containers.

My Code:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('input').keyup(function(){
            if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr("maxlength")){
                $(this).next().focus();
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date" class="container_date">
    <div class="date_day" id="input_day">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_day" id="1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_month" id="input_month">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_month" id="2" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_year" id="input_year">
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="input_year" id="3" value="">
    </div>
</div>


    <div id="time" class="container_time">
        <div class="time_hour" id="input_hour">
            <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_hour" id="1" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="time_minute" id="input_minute">
            <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_minute" id="2" value="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

The Jquery works for input fields in the same div/container, but not in a different one. How to focus also in another div/container?

Comment: but your inputs don't have a `.inputs` class

Comment: @julekgwa yes it must be input without a dot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the index of the current input by searching the matched elements `$('input').index(this)` Then you can select the next input in the matched elements with `.eq(i+1)`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input').keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr("maxlength")){
            var i = $('input').index(this);
            $('input').eq(i+1).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="date" class="container_date">
    <div class="date_day" id="input_day">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_day" id="1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_month" id="input_month">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_month" id="2" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="date_year" id="input_year">
        <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="input_year" id="3" value="">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="time" class="container_time">
    <div class="time_hour" id="input_hour">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_hour" id="1" value="">
    </div>
    <div class="time_minute" id="input_minute">
        <input type="text" maxlength="2" name="input_minute" id="2" value="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @can I've updated my answer so it is a bit clearer. This is a direct solution to your problem, but I think using the tabindex in Martin Schneider's answer is probably better practice for accessibility and updaing.

Answer (score 6):

You could try to get a list of all related input-fields by traversing the DOM up until a certain parent element and looking for each input, determining the current input element and select the next one.

I would propose a different solution: use the tabindex attribute.

```
div class="date_day" id="input_day">
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" tabindex="1" name="input_day" id="1" value="">
</div>
<div class="date_month" id="input_month">
    <input type="text" maxlength="2" tabindex="2" name="input_month" id="2" value="">
</div>
<div class="date_year" id="input_year">
    <input type="text" maxlength="4" tabindex="3" name="input_year" id="3" value="">
</div>
```

With this you can create a non-linear movement in regard to the "next" field. The focus can easily be moved to the next one:

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
  if($(this).val().length==$(this).attr("maxlength")){
        var tabIndex = +$(this).attr('tabindex');
        $('[tabindex=' + (+tabIndex+1) + ']').focus();
  }
});
```

Comment: This has the added benefit of implementing the tabindex attribute. i.e. letting you set your tab order.

Comment: @Martin Schneider is there an alternative of tabindex? Can't use tabindex in the form..

Comment: well tabindex has the advantage of the semantics 'this is the next element that should be focused', but you could nevertheless use any attribute, like the id that you seem to have given each input: `$('input#'+(id+1)).focus()` for example